# Ensuring Maximal Android Version Compatibility

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

I'm new to android development and am inheriting an app that I plan to deploy in a low resource, rural environment. I am still learning about android development, but I was wondering if there were any tools I can use to ensure a wide range of compatibility as my teammates mentioned that I will encounter a wide range of android versions.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.androidpolice.com/googles-latest-android-version-distribution-numbers-show-11-in-dead-heat-with-10/amp/) for some stats about the number of devices at different API levels. Supporting API 16+ would cover the vast majority of devices. And you can make emulators in Android Studio to test on old versions. Also, if the app is already deployed you can get stats about API levels of your users from the Play Console